# Angularfirecollection return object instead of array

Tags: firebase, angularfire

Before using `angularFireCollection()` I was using `angularFire()`. But angularFire listening on `value` instead of `childs` so someone suggest me to use angularFireCollection.

But now angularFireCollection return arrays. =.=

So any idea in this situation?

I want my data return in objects and listening on childs.

Comment: `angularFireCollection` returns an array in order to ensure the order of items in it matches the priorities set on the server. You'll get an array of Objects, what specifically are you trying to do that you can't do with arrays but can with objects?

Comment: The reason I want to use objects is I want to retrieve the keys. You answered it in my previous question. `ng-repeat="(key, val) in objects"`. @Anant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the key names from the array returned by angularFireCollection, you can use the $id property:

```html
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in items">{{item.$id}}: {{item.val}}</li>
</ul>
<script>
  $scope.items = angularFireCollection(new Firebase(url));
</script>
```